# Java: Call/Return Error

Tags: java

I am having some trouble returning matrix data from one method to the main class, I am using:

```
matrix =  setFalse(falseMatrix);
```

to call:

```
public static boolean[][] setFalse (boolean[][] matrix[][]) {

        // Changes each value of the matrix to a false boolean value

        boolean[][] falseMatrix = null;

        for (int r = 0; r < matrix.length; r++ ) {
            for (int c = 0; c < matrix[0].length; c++ ) {
                falseMatrix[r][c] = false;

            }
        }
        return falseMatrix;

    }
```

I am getting the error that falseMatrix cannot be resolved to a variable, but when I make it a parameter I get a fatal error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is currently *very* confused. I suspect you want:

```
public static boolean[][] setFalse(boolean[][] matrix) {
    // Changes each value of the matrix to a false boolean value

    for (int r = 0; r < matrix.length; r++ ) {
        for (int c = 0; c < matrix[r].length; c++ ) {
            matrix[r][c] = false;
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

How you then *call* the method is a different matter. You need to already *have* a variable (or some other expression) of type `boolean[][]`. Unfortunately you haven't shown us any of the context of the calling code.

Comment: Thank you, this is very much what I was looking to accomplish, sorry If I did not provide all the needed context

Answer (score 2):

change

```
(boolean[][] matrix[][]) {
```

to

```
(boolean[][] matrix) {
```

and

```
boolean[][] falseMatrix = null;
```

to

```
boolean[][] falseMatrix = new boolean[matrix.length][];
```

and insert between the two `for`

```
falseMatrix[r] = new boolean[matrix[r].length];
```

and finally change in 2nd `for`

```
matrix[0].length;
```

to

```
matrix[r].length;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
public static boolean[][] setFalse (boolean[][] matrix[][]) {
```

To:

```
public static boolean[][] setFalse (boolean[][] matrix) {
```

Also, initialize your array:

```
    //HERE
    boolean[][] falseMatrix = new boolean[matrix.length];

    for (int r = 0; r < falseMatrix.length; r++ ) {
    //AND HERE
        falseMatrix[r] = new boolean[matrix[0].length];
        for (int c = 0; c < falseMatrix[r].length; c++ ) {
            falseMatrix[r][c] = false;
        }
    }

    return falseMatrix;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (int r = 0; r < matrix.length; r++ ) {
            for (int c = 0; c < matrix[0].length; c++ ) {
```

you should probably change `matrix[0]` to `matrix[r]`.  Not sure if it solves your problem, but Im pretty sure thats what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean[][] falseMatrix = null;
```

`falseMatrix` is a null reference. You have to initialize it to with rows, columns before trying to keep values at it's indices.

Answer (score 0):

On the first line (the calling line) you are using two different variables, `falseMatrix` and `matrix`, since it's giving error on `falseMatrix` then I suppose it's the wrong one.

Answer (score -1):

You need:

```
boolean[][] falseMatrix = new boolean[matrix.length][matrix[0].length];
```